# Is reversing debugging possible on OS X

Tags: macos, debugging, reverse-engineering, replay

I know on Linux gdb is able to record and replay where a executable stepped to, but till now on OS X the feature hasn't been implemented in gdb (7.10), neither the lldb.

I'm wondering if any tools or projects with similar function are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything in the Apple Developer Tools that supports reverse debugging on OS X or iOS.  There may be third party tools but none that I have heard of.